# How can I count frequency of all values in several csv columns

Tags: python, csv

I have several csv columns that store lottery numbers and some other info, like date when the number was drawn. I need to get a dictionary <number drawn, number of times this number occurred throughout all the columns> as my output.
So far I have been able to print number of occurrences in each column individually.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd 
from IPython.display import display

# Turn csv file into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("LOTTOMAX.csv")

# Only select columns that I'm interested in. Csv file contains additional useless info.
selection = df[['NUMBER DRAWN 1', 'NUMBER DRAWN 2', 'NUMBER DRAWN 3', 'NUMBER DRAWN 4',
'NUMBER DRAWN 5', 'NUMBER DRAWN 6', 'NUMBER DRAWN 7']]

# Loop over columns and apply value_counts(). Output to terminal.
for col in selection.columns:
    # I have included this to make terminal output more readable.
    print('-' * 40 + col + '-' * 40 , end='\n')
    display(selection[col].value_counts().to_string())
```

Comment: Use [Collection.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a loop? The question is pretty broad. What have you tried? What format do want as a result?

Comment: I want dictionary of format <Number, how many times it occurred> as my output

Comment: How much Python do you know? Will you edit your question and include some code of your own  attempt?

Comment: I have utilized pandas library. stack() and value_counts(), but I was unable to achieve desired dictionary pair output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this project for fun. Wanted to replicate a feauture on bclc website. Perhaps this will help someone.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read csv file
df = pd.read_csv("LOTTOMAX.csv") #csv file https://www.playnow.com/resources/documents/downloadable-numbers/LOTTOMAX.zip

cols = ['NUMBER DRAWN 1', 'NUMBER DRAWN 2', 'NUMBER DRAWN 3', 'NUMBER DRAWN 4',
'NUMBER DRAWN 5', 'NUMBER DRAWN 6', 'NUMBER DRAWN 7']

results = []

# Add data to a list
for i in cols:
    results += df[i].tolist()

# Count occurrences 
occurr = Counter(results)

# Display histogram
plt.bar(list(occurr.keys()), occurr.values(), color='g')
plt.xlabel("Numbers Drawn")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()
```